# Multiline expressions in swift

Tags: swift, multiline

When is it possible to write multiline expressions in swift?

So far I have encountered a problem with property chaining over multilines.

```
// is it possible to write this statement over multilines, can you split after or before a dot?
return self.anObject.varx(a: true, b: false).vary.varz.veryLongVariableName
```

Comment: Splitting the line before a dot should be possible. Can you provide a _self-contained_ example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: My bad, I'm used to splitting after operators. Like with LINQ queries. Overlook splitting before the dot, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just break the line before dot. I write this kind of code in other languages everyday.

```
class Foo {
    var bar: Foo {
        return self
    }

    var veryLongNameVariable: Foo {
        return self
    }

    func method(i: Int, _: Int) -> Foo {
        return self
    }
}

let f = Foo()
let f2 = f
    .bar
    .method(3, 4)
    .bar
    .bar
    .method(0, 2)
    .veryLongNameVariable
    .veryLongNameVariable

print(f2)
```

Answer (score 1):

A comment can be multiple lines if it extends to the following line without you hitting enter (or adding a new line character).

The easiest place you can hit a new line in actual code is inside of brackets/parenthesis in between comma delimited statements. Statements can be broken up more by actually changing the code, but nothing else is coming directly to mind.

Often times it's considered better practice to use a let statement on part of a statement like you made to split it up and make it more readable.

Whatever problem you are actually running into has nothing to do with multiple lines unless you are actually long enough to receive the warning saying it is too difficult to compute. That warning has always been able to be fixed by just separating the code into more parts. Who wants 1 line that's 200 characters anyhow?

```
let object = self.anObject
let varx = object(a: true,
     b: false)
let vary = varx.vary
let varz = vary.varz
let longName = varz.veryLongVariableName
return longName
```

Comment: That's exactly why I asked the question, all about readability. Have a 80 column ruler set. Was wondering if you can chain properties over multiple lines. But you can't, splitting over let statement is good solution. Thanks.

Comment: I max split it up, including the new line in the varx declaration. I wouldn't chain all object properties in that way. Just do it to the extent that feels the most readable I suppose. Some things have standards on the norm for splitting them, but in the end it is all you or your teams preference.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the expression!

When you split an expression across multiple lines, *remember to always put the dot on the new line*:

```
let s = ""
s.capitalizedString
    .capitalizedString
    .capitalizedString
    .capitalizedString
    .capitalizedString
    .capitalizedString
    .capitalizedString
    .capitalizedString
    .capitalizedString
    .capitalizedString
    .capitalizedString
```

If you put the dot on the same line, it won't compile:

```
var s = ""
s.capitalizedString.
    capitalizedString.
    capitalizedString.
    capitalizedString.
    capitalizedString.
    capitalizedString.
    capitalizedString.
    capitalizedString.
    capitalizedString.
    capitalizedString.
    capitalizedString
```

Another thing that you can do is to turn on line wrapping in Xcode:

[image]

It will look like this:

[image]